# Partly link-only answer persists

Tags: discussion, support

The question: [What do the seasons mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346054/what-do-the-seasons-mean) requires an answer of four parts.

Two of the parts do not make any sense to me (unless I visit the out-of-the-site link the poster urges me to). Especially Autumn (and the other is Summer).

While I am OK to do so, that's not cool, since links die and the answer will he half-invalided for the future users.

I mean in SO, there are tons of answers that were heavily based on links, which have now died, making the answers (partially) useless.

I have let the poster know, but he is stubborn. :)

Is anything else I could do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can edit the answer. Answers that you edit will be reviewed by other members of the community. There's a good discussion of when it is appropriate to edit a post in this FAQ page: “[Edit Questions And Answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)”.